# Obtener datos de usuario logueado Vue/Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js

1. Hola a todos, estoy usando Vue para front y Laravel para el back, necesito mostrar una lista de celulares asignados al usuario logueado pero no se como hacerlo, debo sacar de una relacion pero para eso necesito usar el id del usuario logueado y no se como hacerlo, ¿ideas? OBTENER ID DE USUARIO LOGUEADO.
2. Tambien necesito poder acceder al nombre de una tabla relacionada a otra tabla relacionada, ejemplo: tabla_empleado(id, nombre) tiene relacion con tabla_albañil(id, empleado_id) que tiene relacion con tabla_proyecto(albañil_id), estoy trabando con tabla_proyecto y quiero acceder al campo nombre de la tabla empleado, pero solo consigo llegar hasta albañil y mostrar su id, como hago para mostrar el nombre de una tabla lejana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Laravel para obtener el usuario logeado puedes hacer lo siguiente:

> Auth::user()

y ahi irán todos los datos de la sesión de ese usuario

saludos